# How to convert columns into rows in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Please help me to understand, how to convert columns to rows in MS Access. I have the below table, I would like to convert as the below result table.

```
NoOf_A NoOf_B NoOf_C NoOf_D
200    300    400    500
```

Result Table:

```
Type_OfCValue  Total
NoOf_A          200  
NoOf_B          300
NoOf_C          400
NoOf_D          500
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255423/how-to-simulate-unpivot-in-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT "NoOf_A" AS Type_ofCValue, NoOf_A AS [Value] FROM T1

UNION

SELECT "NoOf_B" AS Type_ofCValue, NoOf_B AS [Value] FROM T1

UNION

SELECT "NoOf_C" AS Type_ofCValue, NoOf_C AS [Value] FROM T1

UNION

SELECT "NoOf_D" AS Type_ofCValue, NoOf_D AS [Value] FROM T1;

Comment: Hello, thank you so much, you are a very professional person. I have accepted the answer.